# webrtc media server - skylink.io or kurento.org

Tags: webrtc

I currently have a product that is used for recording video / screeshare and audio and use APIs supplied by a Opentok WebRTC platform for creating the stream + recording. There are a couple of problems I have ran in to mainly to do with the quality of the recorded file, I'm unable to change resolution and can't pause a record.

So I have started to look at WebRTC media servers such as skylink.io & kurento.org and wanted to know peoples' experiences with using them. Are they easy/quick to use/create? what are your experiences concurrency loads?

Any info on either product would be great.

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge skylink.io is a PaaS service, such as Opentok. This means that with both of them you are not owning the infrastructure. You access a third party infrastructure following a pay-per-use model.

Kurento Media Server, instead, is an open source media server that you need to install and manage in your own servers. Hence, Kurento Media Server cannot be compared with skylink.io because skylink.io is not a media server.

Otherwise, if your questions is on comparing a third-party PaaS with a owned media server, the answer is straighforward.

- The PaaS is simpler to manage for the developer (i.e. you don't need to manage any kind of infrastructure and you forget about security, ugrades, maintenance, etc.)
- The PaaS is less flexible, it has the features the PaaS owner wants to provide. You cannot extend them.
- The PaaS is, at least for high traffic volumes, more expensive. You need to pay for the cost of the infrastructure + the marging associated to the business model of the PaaS owner.

Disclaimer: I'm the lead of Kurento Media Server project and my answer might be biased.